# MediaCodec -- AMediaCodec_start() return -10000, why? how can I solve it?

Tags: c++, error-handling, android-mediacodec

```
void_t destroyCodec(AMediaCodec* codec)
    {
        media_status_t status = AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer(codec, mLastDecodedFrameIndex, true);
        if (status != AMEDIA_OK){
        OMAF_LOG_E("MediaCodec releaseOutputBuffer failed with status = %d", status);
                OMAF_ASSERT(false, "Release output buffer failed!");
            }

        status = AMediaCodec_stop(codec);

        if (status != AMEDIA_OK)
        {
            LOG_E("MediaCodec stop failed with status = %d", status);
            ASSERT(false, "Stop failed!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (codec)
            {
                delete codec;
                codec= nullptr;
            }
        }
        mLastDecodedFrameIndex = -1;
    }
```

```
void_t reCreateCodec(MimeType aType)
{
    if(mCodec){
      destroyCodec(mCodec);
    } 
    mType = aType;
    mCodec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType(mType.getData());
    Assert(mCodec!= NULL,"Failed to Create codec!");

    AMediaFormat* androidMediaFormat = AMediaFormat_new();

    AMediaFormat_setString(androidMediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, mMimeType.getData());

    OMAF_ASSERT((mMimeType == VIDEO_H264_MIME_TYPE || mMimeType == VIDEO_HEVC_MIME_TYPE), "Unsupported mimetype");

    if (mMimeType == VIDEO_H264_MIME_TYPE){
        AMediaFormat_setBuffer(androidMediaFormat, "csd-0", mDecoderConfig.spsData, mDecoderConfig.spsSize);

        AMediaFormat_setBuffer(androidMediaFormat, "csd-1", mDecoderConfig.ppsData, mDecoderConfig.ppsSize);
    }
    else if (mMimeType == VIDEO_HEVC_MIME_TYPE){
        AMediaFormat_setBuffer(androidMediaFormat, "csd-0", mDecoderConfig.configInfoData,mDecoderConfig.configInfoSize);
    }

    AMediaFormat_setInt32(androidMediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_WIDTH, mDecoderConfig.width);
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(androidMediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_HEIGHT, mDecoderConfig.height);

    media_status_t status = AMediaCodec_configure(mCodec, androidMediaFormat, mOutputTexture.nativeWindow, NULL, 0);

    if (status != AMEDIA_OK){
        LOG_E("Could not configure video decoder, status = %d", status);
        AMediaFormat_delete(androidMediaFormat);
        mState = DecoderHWState::ERROR_STATE;
    }
    mState = DecoderHWState::CONFIGURED;
    AMediaFormat_delete(androidMediaFormat);
    media_status_t status = AMediaCodec_configure(mCodec, androidMediaFormat, mOutputTexture.nativeWindow, NULL, 0);
        
    if (status != AMEDIA_OK){
       LOG_E("Could not configure video decoder, status = %d", status);
       AMediaFormat_delete(androidMediaFormat);
    }
        
    status = AMediaCodec_start(mCodec);
    if (status != AMEDIA_OK){
       LOG_E("MediaCodec start failed, status = %d", status);
    }
}
```

the log just shows error `MediaCodec start failed, status = -10000`

so we can assert `AMediaCodec_configure()` works well but `AMediaCodec_start()` fails.

And this error only occurs when we re-Create new Codec for the 8th time. No problem can be found in last 7 times.
`'re-Create' means : check if we have old ones. If so, destroy them and create new one`

After searching for many times, I still have no idea for Error-code `-10000` in MediaCodec.

Here post some source-code in NdkMediaCodec , we can know the error-code `-10000` is returned by the responded `msg` :

```
int AMediaCodec_start(AMediaCodec *mData) {
    return translate_error(mData->mCodec->start());
}

status_t MediaCodec::start() {
    sp<AMessage> msg = new AMessage(kWhatStart, id());

    sp<AMessage> response;
    return PostAndAwaitResponse(msg, &response);
}
```

Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: at a guess you aren't destroying the old ones correctly and the OS limits the number of open codecs you can have, please show a [mre]

Comment: @Alan Birtles  Thanks a lot! At your suggestion, I check my 're-Create', and find out that I just use `delete codec` in stead of  `AMediaCodec_delete(codec)`,which is the std-function in MediaCodec to destroy the codec.

Comment: If you've solved your own problem feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64747733/edit) your question so that it is a [mre] then add an answer, it might help somebody else in the future

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alan Birtles .

At his suggestion, I found that I misuse `delete codec` to destroy the codec. Actually, NdkMediaCodec has its own std::funtion `AMediaCodec_delete()` to destroy the codec.

So the `destroyCodec(AMediaCodec* codec)` should be :

```
   void_t destroyCodec(AMediaCodec* codec)
    {
        media_status_t status = AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer(codec, mLastDecodedFrameIndex, true);
        if (status != AMEDIA_OK){
        OMAF_LOG_E("MediaCodec releaseOutputBuffer failed with status = %d", status);
                OMAF_ASSERT(false, "Release output buffer failed!");
            }

        status = AMediaCodec_stop(codec);

        if (status != AMEDIA_OK)
        {
            LOG_E("MediaCodec stop failed with status = %d", status);
            ASSERT(false, "Stop failed!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (codec)
            {
                status = AMediaCodec_delete(codec);
                if (status == AMEDIA_OK)
                   OMAF_LOG_I("[DECODER] Release codec Success!  %p", codec);
                codec = nullptr;
            }
        }
        mLastDecodedFrameIndex = -1;
    }
```

And the error-code `-10000` probably occurs when there are too much codec-instance for the OS.